# Getting items printed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a for loop in Selenium with Java that will print out the all the item names on the page. I'm having trouble getting the for loop to execute it. It can navigate to the page fine but it won't print out the names of all the items.

```
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver(c);
    driver2.get("https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/");
    driver2.manage().window().maximize();
    driver2.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.continue")).click();
    driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='riotbar-navbar']/a[2]")).click();
    driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toc']/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/a/img")).click();

    //Method for getting number and names of items on the Items page.

    List <WebElement> numberofItems = driver2.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        int a = numberofItems.size();
            System.out.println("Number of Items: " + a);

    List <WebElement> namesofItems = driver2.findElements(By.className("item-name"));
        String[] items = new String[namesofItems.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(WebElement e : namesofItems)
            items[i] = e.getText().toString();
                i++;
```

When I throw in a print statement to try and get something I only get the number 1. I know it's a taxing operation but I want to print all 52 item names is my goal. The problem I'm finding is that each "item-name" is under a different parent "item-grid-(series of numbers). Do I need to navigate into each child and get the class or is there something I'm missing with my current method? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I got 52 as size in the number of items. In the second namesofitems list size is 0. The locator is not correct.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the fact that each individual item name is under a different parent "item-grid-(series of numbers). For example, Abyssal Mask is under "item-grid-3001". Do I need to have a different statement for each one or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath selector for the second part. Your current one is returning 0.

```
List<WebElement> namesofItems = driver2.findElements(By.xpath("//li[not(@style)]//div[@class='item-name']"));
        System.out.println("Number of Items: " + namesofItems.size());

        for(WebElement w:namesofItems)
            System.out.println(w.getText());
```

There are some items which are hidden and if you do not use not(@style) then you will see extra items which are not displayed (eg. an extra item after 'Brawler's Gloves' in the inspect element console. check the style item in the li tag for this extra item. you will notice a **style attribute which is present**. This style is no present in the other **visible** ones).

Comment: Hmm that's still reading out 0 for some reason. They also all have a common CSS and that's "div.item-name" but I'm still having trouble printing with that one as well. Do I need to have an explicit wait for it to run?

Comment: It worked for me without any wait. Try with a thread.sleep to see if it works then you can look at adding an explicit wait.